# Making Samorost 3 moths vibrate: general rules

Tags: samorost-3

In [Samorost 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samorost_3), there are a number of moths and one of the requirements to make progress in the game is to make the moths vibrate. This can be done by trial and error, and it is possible to find a walkthrough that will just give you the solution for each moth individually, but I'm wondering: are there any *general* rules for vibrating Samorost 3 moths?

I'm theorising there must be some unifying methodology, be it mathematical, ideological, spatial, conceptual etc which unifies all of the moth puzzles and can be applied in order to solve any of them. Though understanding this rule might well be a task in itself...?

Update: So far there's one answer which is along the lines of what I'm looking for. Though any alternative approach people could suggest would be more than welcome :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the first moth you encounter:
>  If we call the antennas from left to right `A,B,C,D`
>  The vibrations will go as follows: `A+C+C+B+D+A`

If you want do use the above as it feels like cheating you can do as I did:

Basically:

1. You need to go with what don't feel right, if you think the melody should be slightly more atuned or in harmony, break out of the box of logic you might float around in.
2. Listen with your musical ear, like if you love someone how would you tell them? Would you copy them, enhance how you see them, fade into how they communicate etc?
3. Go with your instinct even though it might not be the logical solution. So if the logical solution is to go with the one you love's melody then try to go with a similar melody but change the pattern a bit.
4. When you've reached that point you know how to solve the moth antenna puzzle.